# How to use button outlet from UItable cell in code

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create a button in each of my UITable cells within my UITableViewController. I have placed a button in my cell, in my storyboard, but when I try to create an outlet in my swift file, I get an error saying that,  "Illegal Configuration: The Buttons outlet from the GroupNamesTable to the UIButton is invalid. Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content." How can I integrate my button from the storyboard to my actual swift file? Would appreciate any suggestions.

```
class GroupNamesTable: UITableViewController {
    @IBOutlet var Buttons: UIButton!
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellidentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        let joinbutton: UIButton = Buttons
        joinbutton.addTarget(self, action: "print", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        cell.addSubview(joinbutton)
        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to use `cell.contentView.subview[]` to get the UIButton. Because your button is already in Storyboard, the index is fixed. And then use `addTarget` to add action.

[image][image]

**CODE**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! UITableViewCell
    var btn : UIButton = cell.contentView.subviews[0] as! UIButton
    btn.addTarget(<#target: AnyObject?#>, action: <#Selector#>, forControlEvents: <#UIControlEvents#>)
    return cell
}
```

Comment: I would appreciate it if you could show that in my code, because it does not seem to be working the way I just implemented it.

Comment: That works! Just one more thing, I can only see the button once I tap the cell. How can I make it automatically appear?

Comment: @Archie It is automatically appear for me.

Comment: Could you show me your Xcode setup, because it is not showing it for me> I have to tap the cell first, then it appears.